# C# Multiply fields of Array elements using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

Let's say I have an array of MyClass objects (not just a `IEnumerable<int>`).
MyClass has a string field (e.g. name) and int filed (e.g. size).
I need to have multiplied sizes of all elements in array as result (`int result = array[0].size*array[1].size*...array[n].size`). 
It is easy to implement using iteration of array, but I wonder how to implement it using lambda.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Aggregate`:

```
  int result = array
    .Select(item => item.size)
    .Aggregate((x, y) => x * y);
```

Comment: I think you need to seed the `Aggregate` with `1` (`.Aggregate(1, (x, y) => x * y)`), otherwise everything gets multiplied by 0. I may be wrong though as I've not tried it!

Comment: @Arno: If no seed is given, the first element of the sequence is taken as seed.

Comment: @Fratyx, I didn't know that. For some reason I thought it used the default value for `TSource` for `x` on the first invocation . So does that mean that `x` and `y` refer to the same element on the first call to the lambda? I think this still might give the wrong result though as the first element would be multiplied twice?

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx): _"The first element of source is used as the initial aggregate value."_ Btw, that is the reason why this overload throws an `InvalidOperationException` if the source doesn't contain elements, as opposed to the other overloads like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548744(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Arno: It takes the first element as source and starts aggregating with the second element. Otherwise it would be a quite useless behaviour :-)

Comment: @Fratyx, thanks for the clarification. I'm now a little bit wiser.